# Apple TV remote loses ability to control old infrared sound bar

Tags: appletv, remote-control

We have an old Vizio sound bar, with infrared remote control. We use the Apple TV 4K remote to "learn" that old remote. This works very well, with the Apple remote able to raise/lower volume and mute.

But… every several months, the Apple TV remote fails to control the sound bar. Pressing buttons on the Apple TV remote has no effect then. The "learned" remote is still listed in the Settings of the Apple TV.

I tried deleting that "learned" item, and re-learning from the sound bar’s original remote control. But no go. I am using the tvOS 17, but the problem occurred long after we upgraded to 17.

This problem has occurred in the past, and been resolved though I cannot remember how.

Any suggestions on restoring the remote control of a IR sound bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the cause but here is the solution, per this Apple Support page, [*If the volume buttons on your Apple TV remote aren't working*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213437):

1. Press and hold the TV/Control Center button and the Volume Down button at the same time for 5 seconds, until light flashes on the Apple TV box. (Those buttons have the television screen icon and the minus-sign icon.)
2. Release the buttons. Then wait 10-15 seconds for a Remote Disconnected notification to appear on your TV screen.
3. Press any button to reconnect the remote control to the Apple TV.

And Bob’s your uncle.

Comment: Explication of the phrase [Bob's your uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle).